# Exclude a free product from total calculation

Tags: commerce

In Drupal Commerce, how can I exclude a product from partial total calculation? The product is inserted as free product via a Commerce Discount rule, but in total calculation it appears and then is subtracted. 
I would exclude this insertion/delete operation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a rule with the event *Calculating the sell price of a product*.

There, you can check for the SKU of the product and set its price to zero (using the *Set data value* action).

You can also use the *Subtract an amount from the unit price* action to assign the value to a price component so that it appears in the totals (this will require extra configuration)

Comment: I've already tried your first advice, but it doesn't work when the product is a gift, so I've put the price of the product to zero and used the "Calculating the sell price of a product" to set the real price when it isn't a gift. 
But this is a weird workaround....

Comment: Yes it is a weird workaround. It may be related to the priority of the rule. Try setting it to the maximum (10) or the minimum (-10). It may be another rule interfering.